# C# Sendkeys slow down / have to press key for sending each line

Tags: c#, performance, sendkeys

is it possible to slow the Sendkeys feature down, when I've set that it sends the keys out of a textbox?

So I mean that it takes longer / that there is a delay before sending each letter?

Ive also thought about if it is possible to have to press a key for sending each line.

I prefer the first option. Hope that is even technically possible.

Thank you for reading this

Comment: If you want to send one line of text then handle key down for "Enter"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meant that I have to press/hold a key that the SendKey function in processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer!
I bet the most people don't need help with this, but why shouldn't I publish the answer I found?

Code:

```
    foreach(char uga in rbox.Text)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
       SendKeys.SendWait(uga.ToString());
     }
```

If you got {ENTER} in the Textbox/String, then do this:
{ENTER} has an alternative keyword.
**`{ENTER}` has "~".** Writing the `{example}` keywords in the string will not work!
Just ENTER has this :( And some other keys, but they dont have keywords in these things: `{example}`

[This site did help me!](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/make-sendkeyssendwait-write-slower)